# Serialising an IRestRequest to unit test a client

Tags: c#, unit-testing, restsharp

I am in the process of writing some unit tests for an RPC client that uses RestSharp. As part of my tests, I want to check that the client sends the correct API requests, so I need to serialise the `IRestRequest` into some form of string that is easy to compare.

I have tried the following, but it doesn't seem to include the parameters in the body:

```
var request = new XmlRpcRestRequest($"{url}.doSomething");
request.AddXmlRpcBody(parameter1, parameter2);
Assert.AreEqual("...", request.XmlSerializer.Serialize(request));
```

Is there a better, more standard way of doing this so that I can check that my RPC client executes the right request?

Answer (score 0):

The best thing I could come up with was the following. Please let me know if you come up with something better though:

```
Assert.AreEqual("...", request.Parameters.Skip(1).First().Value.ToString());
```